# Empty Character Constant

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to bypass error C2137 on Visual Studio Community 2015? I am removing characters with `stringstream` but I do not want to replace them (even with a blank space), I want to erase them so, if I want to remove all `'o'` in `'cool'` it becomes `'cl'` and not `'c  l'`. I saw in Stroustrup's book he wrote a `if (...) ch = '';` but my compiler returns me an error and my best proxy is white space that's still unacceptable.

Here's my function with C2137:

```
string rem_vow(string& s)
{
    for (char& c : s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'A': case 'a': case 'E': case 'e': case 'I': 
        case 'i': case 'O': case 'o': case 'U': case 'u':
            c = '';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

**EDIT:**

That's the code I saw in the book:

[image: Code Example]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which book was that, and which edition of it?

Comment: @Borgleader Programming Principles and Practice using C++ / 2nd edition C++11/14

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: That's expected behaviour. A character literal must contain at least one character - so an error is appropriate.

Comment: @skyking I know because I logically think that compilers never lies I wanted to better understand how is that possible (see posted image)

Comment: @LeonardoUrbano Did you see the comment next to that line? It's not an empty character (doesn't exist), it's a space.

Comment: There is a space between the single quotes in the book. The comment says  that.

Comment: It ought to be strictly forbidden to write code in a book using variable width font. How can the reader then tell if there's a space character between the apostrophes?

Comment: Don't know guys.. I was just trying to understand that! So I could only use  `remove_if` or `erase` right?

Comment: @Leonardo Urbano Try to use an ink-eraser. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's an option man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in order to remove a character in a string you will have to move the rest of the string one step, you cannot simple replace it with "empty" character. You could use the `erase` method though, but then you should probably not do that while iterating the string.

What you probably should do is to build a new string as you traverse the original string, something like:

```
string rem_vow(string const& s)
{
    string res;

    for (char c : s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'A': case 'a': case 'E': case 'e': case 'I':
        case 'i': case 'O': case 'o': case 'U': case 'u':
            //c = ' ';
            break;
        default:
            res.push_back(c);
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```