# Count no. of words in a string in C programming ( I am getting empty character constant error)

Tags: c

My code was to count no of words in the string.
But (a[i]=='') is showing empty character constant error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char a[20];

    int i,c1=0,c2=0;

    scanf("%[^\n]",a);

    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        c1++;

        if(a[i]=='')

        c2++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",c1);

    printf("%d",c2+1);

    return 0;
}
```

For input - tom is here

I expect the output to be -11
                           3

Compilation error- In function 'main':

prog.c:10:15: error: empty character constant
      if(a[i]=='')
               ^

Comment: What does `if(a[i]=='')` mean to you?

Comment: What do you want `''` to do or represent?

Comment: In contrast to empty string literal (`""`), character literals *always* need to contain a character (exactly one). Replace `''` with `' '`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Why did you decide to make that a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty Character Constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878625/empty-character-constant)  (maybe that's why...)

Comment: @Ry-    if(a[i]==' ') means spaces between words . If I could count the spaces between the words of the string then possibly the count of words will be equal to 1 more than the count.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you so much . I got the output now.

Comment: @Aconcagua: note that although it is normal to use a single character in an integer character constant, the standard explicitly says (C11 [§6.4.4 ¶2 Character constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p2): _An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes…_ . Granted, multiple characters in a character constant have an implementation-defined value and are generally not very useful, but don't overstate your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char str[50];

    int i, numberOfWords=0;

    gets(str);

    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if(str[i] == 32) //ascii code of space is 32
            numberOfWords++;
    }
    printf("number of words = %d\n", numberOfWords + 1);
    //adding 1 to numberOfWords because if there are two words, there will be 2-1=1 space between them. eg= "Hello World"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok..the ascii of space is serving the purpose. Thanks. Just that the "gets" won't work since it has become obsolete and is dangerous to use. Also the code will have a compile time error since 'a' (in a[i]==32) is undefined. pls change it to "str". Thanks again

Comment: No; please do not suggest the use of 32 in place of `' '` (where there's a simple space between the two quotes).

Comment: `' '` vs. `32`: Use the former, if you encode characters for your local system (as in given case), you'll stay portable this way. Use the latter, if you need to enforce ASCII (compatible) output (e. g. to a file or socket), even if local encoding might differ. Better in the latter case, then, would be using some function like `toascii(' ')` or `toascii("someString")`, if it exists on such system...

Comment: Note that most people would regard a string like `" one  or  more  words "` as containing 4 words, even though there are 8 blanks in the string (one at the start, two between each word, and another at the end).  And that's before we deal with tabs, newlines, etc.  Your algorithm is a bit too simplistic.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to empty string literal (`""`), character literals always need to contain a character (exactly one)<sup>*</sup>. Replace `''` with `' '` and you code should compile at least.

However, the code as is will count the number of spaces. What will happen if a string contains more than one subsequent space? Additionally, you might want to consider tabs as well? And how would you want to interpret punctuation marks? Part of words or separator? And what about numbers?

Depending on how you answer all these questions, you might need to vary the condition in code below. In any case, I propose a stateful iteration over your input:

```
int isSeparator = 1; // so you will count the first word occuring, too, even if starting
                     // at first character of the string
for(char const* s = str; *s; ++s)
{
    if(isalnum((unsigned char)*s)) // requires <ctype.h> header; modify condition
                                   // appropriately if you want different
                                   // characters to count as word parts
    {
        wordCount += isSeparator;
        isSeparator = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        isSeparator = 1;
    }
}
```

<sub><sup>*</sup>Actually, the standard [does](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p2) allow multi-byte characters, so to be precise, we'd need to state *'at least one character'*, but these multi-byte characters have implementation defined meaning and usually aren't useful anyway, so for practical reasons, we might stay with the technically less correct *'exactly one character'*...</sub>